# How to protect against XSS attacks in Grails app

Tags: grails, xss, grails-orm

In my Grails app I'm extracting text from the `params` and using that as parameters in my Domain queries:

Example:

```
def color = Colors.findByName(params.colorname)
```

I imagine someone could fiddle with the `params.colorname` parameter to run bad queries against my `mysql` database.

What are some of the good practices to protect against things like these?

Comment: I believe you are thinking of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) and not [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)?

Comment: Html cleaner plugin can help against sanitizing user input http://nimavat.me/blog/sanitize-user-input-with-html-cleaner-plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you render a field in your view that could potentially contain an XSS attack, you need to  encode it as HTML. You should make all fields that contain user input are encoded. All of the standard Grails tags encode as HTML. If you use `${}` in a view though, that's where you can run into trouble. You need to either manually encode it like `${colorname.encodeAsHTML()}` or use a tag like `fieldValue` if it's a bean property.

You can also set the global default codec with `grails.views.default.codec = "html"` in `Config.groovy`.

Watch out for double encoding and making sure you encode as HTML in your custom tags.

You also reference SQL injection attacks, which are different from XSS attacks. You're only at risk of SQL injection if you're writing your own SQL or HQL and directly interpolating user input into the SQL/HQL. That means do `Colors.executeQuery("from Colors where name like ?", params.colorname)` instead of `Colors.executeQuery("from Colors where name like $params.colorname")`.

Comment: "All of the standard Grails tags encode as HTML."  That is not true prior to the brand new versions 2.2.2 and 2.1.5.  `g.message` did not encode.  That has been [resolved in the new versions](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7170).

Comment: Double encoding is less of an issue as per Grails 2.3. I can recommend the source link for anyone looking into this question.

Source: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.5/guide/security.html